# creating context menu in Android

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I'm trying to create an android context menu (the one that pops-up when you press the 'menu' button'). I've read all the tutorials I could find and nothing helped. I'm new to android developing.

I've created the menu.xml file but I don't understand how to give functionality to ID's. This is how my code looks:

```
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        newGame();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The thing that I don't get: what to do with 'newGame();' and 'showHelp();'. I wish that when I click on a menu button a new activity starts. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is you have code is for option menu not for context menu
you can call new activity like below

1. You can directly call a new activity without using option menu by

   ```
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewGame.class);
   startActivity(myIntent);
   ```
2. if you want to give option to user on press menu button then try below code

   ```
   @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

           menu.add(0, 0, 0, "New Game");
           menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Help");
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       }

   @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

           if(item.getTitle().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("New Game")) {

               Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewGame.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
             }
               else if(item.getTitle().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("Help")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Help", 2000).show();
                    }
           }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewGame.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Have you read about [how activity works](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This starts the activity NewGame

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewGame.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```